# fb:comments-count tag not working in FF

Tags: facebook, firefox, tags, count, comments

Can anyone test the fb:comments-count tag on Firefox? It isn't working here, it worked well untill today, I've checked on IE and Chrome and everything's fine.

Even on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ it isn't working it shows:

**Will emit:
awesome comments**

instead of:
**Will emit:
X awesome comments**

(X=number of comments in the url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine with Mac+Firefox.
I just upgraded my Firefox this morning, though.
[image: fb:comments-count tag on Firefox]

Comment: thanks Hagiwara, it actually did the job. Updating to FF 13.0 solved the problem :)